# How to expand a Table Cell with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-table, expand

I want to have a table/list that has a certain Event with date and title in every row and once you click the row it expands to show photo documentation of that Event.

I know this would be easy with divs, but I need the tabular layout for the date / title / etc.
Is there a way to do the same with tables, but that the Content that appears includes all table cells (photos appear underneath as if all td have been combined to one again)?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what exactly it is you're trying to do, but you could use an extra tr with display:none under each event tr. Then just toggle it with jQuery on click.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you have something like

```
 <table>
   <tr><td>Data</td><td style="display: none;"><img src=""/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Data</td><td style="display: none;"><img src=""/></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Data</td><td style="display: none;"><img src=""/></td></tr>
   ...
 </table>
```

And when user click on row, last row change display at for example block?

If its true, you can:

```
 $('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).find('td:last').toggle();
 });
```